# Auto-generating dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm converting a project to maven projects. So I want all dependencies in pom.xml will be autogenerated from library (contains about 100 jar files, and doing it manually may waste much time). Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JBoss Tools contain some Maven integrations, which can do that. You can find more about that [here](https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/12/10/jboss-tools-4-and-developer-studio-6-is-ready), and [there](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/420896#.UNALfm9-VzY) is the installation link.